# Guardar en base de datos si no existe - Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy realizando una función que se encarga de guardar los datos de un formulario en dos bases de datos, la primera llamada users y la segunda empresa.

Explico su funcionamiento como sería, cuando creamos un usuario en el formulario al pulsar guardar si todo es correcto los datos se guardan en la tabla users y el texto destinado a nombre de empresa va a otra tabla tambien llamada empresa, por el contrario si todo es correcto pero el nombre de la empresa ya existe en la base de datos solo guardaremos los nuevos datos de usuario.

```
 public function guardar()
    {

        helper('text');

        $users = new UserModel();
        $modelEnterprise = new EmpresaModel();

        $validacion = $this->validate([
            'name'          => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
            'surname'       => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]',
            'enterprise'    => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]',
            'nif'           => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[9]|regex_match[/^([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])[0-9]{7}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])$/]',
            'email'         => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email]',
            'password'      => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[200]',
            'confpassword'  => 'matches[password]'
        ]);

        if (!$validacion) {

            $session = session();
            $session->setFlashdata('mensaje', 'Por favor, revise la información');

            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        } else {
            $datos = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_surname'     => $this->request->getVar('surname'),
                'user_enterprise'     => $this->request->getVar('enterprise'),
                'user_nif'     => $this->request->getVar('nif'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'id_rol'    => $this->request->getVar('id_rol'),
                'user_accept'    => $this->request->getVar('user_accept'),
                'user_password' => password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
            ];
            $dataE = [
                'nombre_empresa'     => $this->request->getVar('enterprise'),
            ]; 

            $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
            $builder = $db->table('empresa');
            $empresas = $builder->select('nombre_empresa');

            if($empresas == $dataE){
            //guardamos los datos de usuario en la tabla users 
            $users->insert($datos);
            }else{
             //guardamos la empresa en la tabla empresa  
             $modelEnterprise->insert($dataE);
             //guardamos los datos de usuario en la tabla users 
             $users->insert($datos);
            }

        }
        return $this->response->redirect(site_url('/admin/usersList'));
    }
```

Aunque por alguna razón no logro dar con la condición adecuada que compruebe si esta entrada ya existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No uso codeIgniter, pero mirando [su documentación](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#select), parece que con esta línea:

```php
$empresas = $builder->select('nombre_empresa');
```

tan solo defines la consulta, por lo tanto lo que quizás necesitas hacer es esto en su lugar:

```php
$empresas = $builder->select('nombre_empresa')->get()->getResultArray();
```

para obtener el resultado de la misma y almacenarlo en la variable *$empresas* en forma de array asociativo, gracias al [getResultArray()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#getresultarray).

Luego, suponiendo que esta nueva línea devuelve un array asociativo con los nombres de empresa, lo que debes modificar es la siguiente línea:

```php
if($empresas == $dataE){
```

por esta otra:

```php
if (in_array($dataE, array_values($empresas))) {
```

donde usamos la función [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) para detectar si ese nombre de empresa ya existe en los valores (gracias a [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php)) del array asociativo de $empresas.

Comment: no me ha funcionado

Comment: Revisa mi última actualización de mi respuesta y dime si ahora si te funciona o no

Comment: me ha funcionado perfecto! como habias puesto antes con el  $userEmpresas = $builder->select('nombre_empresa')
                                                                    ->get()
                                                                    ->getResultArray();   y llamando a if (in_array($dataE, array_values($userEmpresas))) , muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Pues vaya, me alegro que te haya funcionado... seguí leyendo cosas de codeigniter y me pareció que no iba a funcionar y por eso volví a actualizar la respuesta. Acabo de revertir mi respuesta a la que dices que si te ha funcionado. Si es la correcta puedes aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa, gracias.

Comment: muchisimas gracias! la verdad que soy super novata con codeigniter y me han pedido que haga un proyecto y me estoy tirando de los pelos un poco jajajajaja

Comment: pues anda que yo... es la primera vez que respondo algo de el mirando su documentación :-)  (de todos modos lo mio es PHP puro, por lo tanto más o menos supongo que lo pillo mejor que tu ahora mismo, aunque con dudas pues no tengo el escenario montado para probar mis respuestas).  Saludos!!